# migrating to a bigger server - how to copy over differences

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-2017

We have a very large database, one table (logs) contains the majority of the data (around 13 billion rows) total database size is approx 6.5TB and I have 900gb of space remaining before server is full.

We have a delete script for old data, but it doesn't effect size, as indexes are fragmented, it would be nice to reclaim this but i know it will introduce a huge downtime if i rebuild the one big index.

The system is always on, we do have quiet periods like sunday night, but any downtime needs to be max 2 hours.

I was planning on copying over the 1TB .bak file to new server, restore, rebuild indexes, then I somehow need to look at the differences between what changes, and update the new server with these differences (new or updates records)

My question is:
Is there a free tool built into sql server that can detect differences, and copy over new/changed data if I "link" the servers? (the one big table does not allow updates, only inserts/deletes)

We are using sql server 2017 ent
As a side note and for full picture, we do not use compression (row or page, this is a different route we are looking at too - if we can do without down time)

Comment: A common method I have seen to achieve this is log shipping - [Move SQL databases to a different server using SQL Server log shipping](https://www.sqlshack.com/move-sql-databases-to-a-different-server-using-sql-server-log-shipping/)

Comment: I'd mark this comment by @ScottHodgin as the answer. Log Shipping is the standard approach to this exact problem.

Comment: But with Log Shipping you can't "restore (with recovery), rebuild indexes".  You end up with a physical copy of the source database.  But it's not obviously necessary to rebuild indexes or reorganize data as part of the migration, and I would normally recommend _not_ doing that, and defering any reorganization to later when you implement row, page, or ColumnStore compression.  The normal solution for keeping two databases _logically_ in sync after a one-time copy is Transactional Replication.

Comment: Have you looked at partitioning and partitioned indexes? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: thanks, the 2nd server is not local, and also the recovery model is simple, so this rules out log shipping.  we did need to rebuild indexes, and that will take a number of hours with online=off, so i need to be able to get the latest data after this maintenance

Comment: I have looked at partitioning in the past, and its something to consider, but for now i need to move to new server whereby it buys us time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) is meant to capture changes that happen in tables and offers you a way to then read what those changes are to synchronize data to a target server.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more like schema changes? unless i've read that wrong?

Comment: "Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that applies to a SQL Server table."